# Rails form_for in each row of a table (with jQuery datatable) has Routing Error: No route matches [POST]

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, form-for

The case is I want to have a table, each row of which is a table to UPDATE an individual record, not complex stuff. Here's the code:

```
%table.table.datatable
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Post ID
      %th Name
      %th Title
      %th
  %tbody
    -if @posts.present?
      - @posts.each do |post|
        %tr
          = simple_form_for post, url: admin_post_path(post), method: :put do |f|
            %td
              = post.id
            %td
              = post.author.name
            %td
              = f.input :title, label: false, input_html: {class: 'input-medium'}
            %td
              = f.submit 'Update', class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Looks simple enough, but it doesn't work with error:

```
Routing Error: No route matches [POST]
```

However this works by removing jQuery datatable:

```
-#from %table.table.datatable    
%table.table
```

Here's part of my routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin, :path => 'welab' do
  ...
  resources :posts
  ...
end
```

The solution could be a workaround for updating 'title'. However can't I have jQuery datatable in this case then?

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file please.  Based on the path helper it looks like you need to define `simple_form_for [admin, post]`.

Comment: vinodadhikary, routes.rb is here now...As the second solution works, I don't think it's a problem with the settings in routes

Comment: It looks like you are using `form` and `tr` in a wrong way, the format `<tr><form><td>` is INVALID in most of browsers, you should avoid to use `form` in `tr`. If it's a must,  try using nested table such as `<tr><td><form><table>....</table></form></td></tr>` instead.

Comment: Bigxiang, thanks but I doubt if datatable works with tables in two layers